# Don't trigger main container click if clicking in specific child element

Tags: javascript, event-bubbling

I have a click listener attached to my `#main` container

```
main.addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log("clicked main");
});
```

Within my main container I have an #element also with a click listener

```
element.addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log("clicked element but dont trigger main click");
});
```

**How do I avoid triggering the `#main` click when clicking within `#element` ?**

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gufo7mmc/1/

Answer (score 1):

Use [event.stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ar/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

```
element.addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log("clicked element but dont trigger main click");
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

```js
var main = document.getElementById("main");
var element = document.getElementById("element");
var textElement = document.getElementById("text");

main.addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log("clicked main");
});

main.addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {
    textElement.style.visibility = "visible";
    console.log("trigger on everything except #element");
});

main.addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
    textElement.style.visibility = "hidden";
});

element.addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log("clicked element but dont trigger main click");
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
#main {
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 600px;
    
    background-color: red;
}

#element {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    
    background-color: green;
}

#text {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    top: 200px;
    
    background-color: blue;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <div id="element"></div>
    <div id="text">HELLO</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Ammar - thanks a bunch! It works. May I ask - could the same logic be applied to the mouseenter event? When doing mouseenter on #element, then I dont want to trigger mouseenter from #main

Comment: @user1231561, yes, I believe this works generally for all standard events

Comment: Just tried adding event.stopPropagation(); to the #element mouseenter listener - that doesn't seem to work atleast :/

Comment: @user1231561, it seems that it is firing the `mouseenter` of the parent before that of the child. http://jsfiddle.net/gufo7mmc/2/

Comment: Yup... Trying to figure out how to handle this scenario... Just to be clear, the fiddle you did triggers mouse mouseenter functions when hovering #element, right?

Comment: @user1231561, yes. I suggest for mouseenter events you rearrrange your code so there isnt parent/children events